# How to fix the Flutter Installation

Tags: flutter

[image]`` ` ``

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[!] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.13.7, on macOS 14.1 23B5067a darwin-x64, locale
    en-IN)
    ! Warning: `dart` on your path resolves to
      /usr/local/Cellar/dart/3.1.3/libexec/bin/dart, which is not inside your
      current Flutter SDK checkout at /Users/pruthviraj/flutter. Consider adding
      /Users/pruthviraj/flutter/bin to the front of your path.
```

I installed Flutter properly by the following docs, I expected it would Tick mark (Success)

Answer (score 0):

Did you set the system environmental variables correctly?
If not all you have to do is, go to the extracted flutter sdk directory. Then go to bin folder. Copy the path of bin folder. Press windows key and search for environmental variables. Then click on Edit environmental variables and on System Varibles you will see a list of items. Find 'path' in the list. Click on it and Click Edit. Click New and paste the copied path to the new field. Click Ok/Apply for all the windows. Restart your system. Open terminal and try

```
flutter doctor -v
```

Hope this resolves the issue. If not please ask.

Answer (score 0):

First, add the Flutter SDK's `bin` directory to your system's `PATH`.

You can do this by adding the following line to your shell profile file (e.g., `~/.bashrc`, `~/.bash_profile`, `~/.zshrc`, or `~/.profile`, depending on your shell:

```bash
export PATH="$PATH:/Users/pruthviraj/flutter/bin" # Path to Flutter SDK
```

After adding the line to your shell profile, save the file and then run the following command to apply the changes:

```bash
source ~/.bashrc  # or source ~/.bash_profile, source ~/.zshrc, source ~/.profile
```

Run flutter doctor again to check if the warning is gone.